# Adding buddypress profile menu items in wordpress primary menu

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

Is it possible to add buddypress profile menu in primary menu of the wordpress them. If is possible please guide me how can I do this. I also want to remove counts in primary menu only.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. 
Here is an appropriate page in BuddyPress codex: https://codex.buddypress.org/getting-started/buddypress-links-in-wordpress-menus/

Below is a small excerpt from that page:

---

Links include: Sitewide Activity, Members Directory, Groups Directory, and/or Blogs Directory (multisite only).

1. Navigate to Appearance > Menus.
2. Create a new menu.
3. Under the “Pages” section, select the links to the BuddyPress pages.
4. Click on the “Add to Menu” button.
5. Arrange the menu links as you like it.
6. Click on “Save the Menu” button.
7. Go to the “Manage Locations” tab and assign this menu to a theme menu location.
8. Click save and refresh your site to see your new custom menu in place.

You can also add links specific to the Logged-in Member only (all profile links).